# Amazon RDS Endpoint internal

Tags: amazon-ec2, rds

How can I make ec2 instance communicate with rds instance on aws by internal ip address or dns? 
I only see public dns like `xxx.cehmrvc73g1g.eu-west-1.rds.amazonaws.com:3306`
Will internal ipaddress will be faster than public dns?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out the AWS EC2 docs: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-instance-addressing.html#concepts-private-addresses.

It doesn't appear that this necessarily applies to RDS, however.

Comment: Yes, It automatically translate enpoin to internal ip if I connect to RDS from inside aws network.

Comment: _"If the DB instance is designated as publicly accessible, its DNS endpoint resolves to the private IP address from within the VPC. It resolves to the public IP address from outside of the VPC."_ [source](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_VPC.WorkingWithRDSInstanceinaVPC.html#USER_VPC.Hiding)

Answer (score 37):

A note for posterity, ensure that you enable DNS on the VPC Peering link!
[image]

> #### Enabling DNS Resolution Support for a VPC Peering Connection
>
> To enable a VPC to resolve public IPv4 DNS hostnames to private IPv4
> addresses when queried from instances in the peer VPC, you must modify
> the peering connection.
>
> Both VPCs must be enabled for DNS hostnames and DNS resolution.
>
> To enable DNS resolution support for the peering connection
>
> 1. Open the Amazon VPC console at https://console.aws.amazon.com/vpc/.
> 2. In the navigation pane, choose Peering Connections.
> 3. Select the VPC peering connection, and choose Actions, Edit DNS
>    Settings.
> 4. To ensure that queries from the peer VPC resolve to private IP
>    addresses in your local VPC, choose the option to enable DNS
>    resolution for queries from the peer VPC.
> 5. If the peer VPC is in the same AWS account, you can choose the option
>    to enable DNS resolution for queries from the local VPC. This ensures
>    that queries from the local VPC resolve to private IP addresses in the
>    peer VPC. This option is not available if the peer VPC is in a
>    different AWS account.
> 6. Choose Save.
> 7. If the peer VPC is in a different AWS account, the owner of the peer
>    VPC must sign into the VPC console, perform steps 2 through 4, and
>    choose Save.

Comment: Thanks! Didn't know about this one! Strange it isn't a default.

Comment: Note that you can't do this if you're trying to do peering across different regions. :( Still looking for a solution in that case.

Comment: Can this be changed to the Accepted Answer?

Comment: It does work across regions, but you have to enable it separately on both ends.

Answer (score 15):

You can use the "Endpoint" DNS name. It will resolve to the internal IP when used within the VPC and resolves to a public ip when used outside of your AWS network. You should never use the actual IP address because the way the RDS works it could possibly change in the future.

If you ping it from your EC2 (on the same VPC) server you can verify this.

It is amazing to see the amount of down votes I've got given that my answer is the only correct answer, here is 2 other sources:

https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=70112

> You can use the "Endpoint" DNS name. It will resolve to the internal IP when used within EC2.

https://serverfault.com/questions/601548/cant-find-the-private-ip-address-for-my-amazon-rds-instance[2](https://serverfault.com/questions/601548/cant-find-the-private-ip-address-for-my-amazon-rds-instance)

> The DNS endpoint provided in the AWS console will resolve to the internal IPs from within Amazon's network.

Comment: Doesn't work with VPC peering. When peering into the VPC of the RDS instance, the endpoint doesn't resolve to internal IP when being used from within anoher VPC.

Comment: @Ashesh what you are describing is irrelevant to the question here, and thanks for the -1.

Comment: It isn't irrelevant and your answer is misleading. If the RDS instance is publicly accessible, its endpoint never resolves to the internal IP from another VPC (and hence your assumption about 'inside EC2' fails here). It'll always resolve to the external IP. 
The RDS instance has to be non-publicly accessible to have an endpoint that resolves to an internal IP.

Comment: I think this answer is absolutely correct. The original question is not talking about VPC peering.

Comment: @Ashesh see filipe-alvarez 's answer regarding this

Comment: @TJBiddle Are you trying to convince this guy after 2 years. lol.

Comment: @Neo  Hey - if it helps someone else 2 years from now!

Comment: @Neo Mine resolves to the external IP even when connecting from inside the VPC :( -- Any ideas?!

Comment: _"If the DB instance is designated as publicly accessible, its DNS endpoint resolves to the private IP address from within the VPC. It resolves to the public IP address from outside of the VPC."_ [source](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_VPC.WorkingWithRDSInstanceinaVPC.html#USER_VPC.Hiding)

Answer (score 0):

When resolving your RDS instance from within the same VPC the internal IP is returned by the Amazon DNS service and should return the internal IP address if it is in the same VPC. You shouldn't need to do any anything.

If the RDS instance is externally accessible you will see the external IP from outside the VPC. However, **if the EC2 instance NOT available publiclaly accessible the internal IP address is returned for both the external and internal lookups**.

*Will internal ip address will be faster than the external address supplied by public dns?*
Most likely as the packets will need to be routed out of the vpc and then back in when using the external addresses, increasing latency.

It also requires that your EC2 instances have a public IP or NAT gateway along with appropriate security groups and routes, increasing cost, increasing complexity and reducing security.

Comment: I feel like this answer might contain information that would be useful to me, but I can't quite understand what you're saying needs to be done.

Answer (score 0):

its pretty easy, telnet your RDS endpoint using command prompt on windows or through unix terminal

for example: telnet "**you RDS endpoint**" "**Port**"

trying to connect "**You get your RDS internal IP here**"