# Accessing RDS from EC2 instance in separate VPC

Tags: amazon-web-services, networking, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds, amazon-vpc

My setup is very similar to the one presented here - [Why can't I connect AWS RDS instance from EC2 instance in another VPC after peering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46312956/why-cant-i-connect-aws-rds-instance-from-ec2-instance-in-another-vpc-after-peer)

I have 2 VPC's `VPC A` and `VPC B`

I have an RDS instance and an EC2 instance (`EC2 A`) in `VPC A` - I can access the RDS instance from `EC2 A` by running something like `mysql -u sa -pPASSWORD -h db-prod.sdfsdfewfwe.us-east-2.rds.amazonaws.com`

I have another EC2 instance (`EC2 B`) in `VPC B` and I'd like to be able to run the same `mysql` command to access the RDS instance.

I set up a peering connection between `VPC A` and `VPC B` so my route table looks like the following:

```
RDS VPC
Destination      Target
172.31.0.0/16    local
10.0.0.0/16      pcx-xyz123

EC2 VPC
Destination      Target
10.0.0.0/16      local
172.31.0.0/16    pcx-xyz123
```

I can now ssh from `VPC A` -> `VPC B` and vice versa, but I still cannot access the RDS instance.

The only way I am able to do it is to set up an SSH tunnel like so:

`ssh -i "key.pem" ubuntu@172.31.0.0 -L 3307:db-prod.sdfsdfewfwe.us-east-2.rds.amazonaws.com:3306 -N`

I can then access the RDS from `VPC B` by running:

`mysql -u sa -pPASSWORD -h 127.0.0.1 -P 3307`

I would like to avoid this, and set up my networking properly to resolve the RDS access from `VPC B`

**Update:**

@detzu Thanks for the response.

RDS has 2 subnets, `db-subnet` and `accessible-subnet`

`accessible-subnet`:

```
11.234.52.0/24     local
11.234.53.0/24     local
11.241.52.0/24     pcx-034d57cb727bbf9ec
0.0.0.0/0          igw-003f4bff3126fc2e9
```

`db-subnet`:

```
11.234.52.0/24     local
11.234.53.0/24     local
11.241.52.0/24     pcx-034d57cb727bbf9ec
0.0.0.0/0          igw-003f4bff3126fc2e9
```

`VPC B` has one subnet `inaccessible-subnet`:

```
11.234.52.0/24     pcx-034d57cb727bbf9ec
11.241.52.0/24     local
0.0.0.0/0          igw-01fd2dbb6bee81525
```

RDS Security group:

```
CIDR/IP - Inbound   33.140.253.74/32
CIDR/IP - Inbound   11.234.52.0/24
CIDR/IP - Inbound   11.241.52.0/24
CIDR/IP - Outbound  0.0.0.0/0
```

**Update 2**

RDS Security group rules

Inbound:

```
MYSQL/Aurora   TCP   3306   33.140.253.74/32
MYSQL/Aurora   TCP   3306   11.234.52.0/24
MYSQL/Aurora   TCP   3306   11.241.52.0/24
```

Outbound:

```
All traffic    All   All    0.0.0.0/0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is the RDS instance in the same subnet with EC2 A ? if not , please provide the routing table for the RDS subnet ( usually private subnet ).

An RDS has a subnet group, a subnet group has at least 2 subnets, please check the route tables for all subnets involved.

Please check the VPC security group for RDS , if possible copy here ( hash public IP's or other private info  ). RDS has 2 security groups, check the one configured in your RDS as VPC security group.

Update 2 : Thank you , the route tables look good. I don't see any issues !

Please add the VPC security group rules from here ( red rectangle) : 
[image]

click on the link and copy the inbound and outbound rules , thank you !

Comment: not sure about the 52 and 53 networks , sometimes are in the routing tables sometimes not . Please use in every routing table and security group  11.234.52.0\23 instead of 11.234.52.0\24 and 11.234.53.0\24 . This will make everything clear . After the change please check , and if it's not working please update the tables here. Check if the tunnel is still working . Thank you !

Comment: Thank you. this ended up working. Also turned on DNS resolution on `VPC B`. Which may have helped. appreciate all the support

Comment: great! I'm happy I could help !