# RDS instance resolving to public IP address when connected to AWS ClientVPN

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I setup an AWS ClientVPN in our company and it is working fine when connecting to our internal AWS resources. However I'm having issue with RDS.

I have an RDS instance which is set to Public (this need to be public as some public resources needs to connect to this RDS). We can connect to the RDS instance from any of our ec2 instance, but when connecting to the rds locally while connected to ClientVPN, we simply can't.

If I nslookup the RDS while inside on one of my ec2-instance, it is resolving to private IP.
If I nslookup from local, it will resolve to the public IP.
If I nslookup from local while connected to AWS ClientVPN, it will still resolve to the public IP. I think this is where the problem is, it should resolve to the private IP address?

Anyone can give me some tips regarding this?
Thanks!

Comment: Have a read of this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21089582/amazon-rds-endpoint-internal specifically the top voted answer (not the accepted one).